# How to modify XML tag in Java?

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have xml file with tag as following :

```
<sometag/>
```

I want to modify this tag as following :

```
<sometag>somevalue</sometag>
```

initially I tried to delete element and create new element, that doesnt work. then I get to know that there is already a method to rename a tag, I tried following code, but dont know how to add value (somevalue) for this renamed element(sometag).

```
NodeList scpNodes=doc.getElementsByTagName("sometag");
    for (int i = 0; i < scpNodes.getLength(); i++) {
        Element toBeReplaced=(Element) scpNodes.item(i);
        doc.renameNode(toBeReplaced, toBeReplaced.getNamespaceURI(),"sometag");        
     // how to append value ?
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean `<sometag>somevalue</sometag>`?

Comment: did the answer below solved your problem ?

Comment: yes, its working fine, thanks for help !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to call

```
toBeReplaced.setTextContext("someValue");
```

and get rid of

```
doc.renameNode(toBeReplaced, toBeReplaced.getNamespaceURI(),"sometag");
```